# The MGF of a PDF confusion

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

A random variable has a pdf given by
$$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            x & \quad 0 \leq x<1 \\
            2-x & \quad 1 \leq x < 2
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

I am then told to find the MGF, M(t), which I got $$M(t) = \frac{e^{2t}-2e^t+1}{t^2}$$ and I'm almost certain that this is correct. Then I'm asked to find the value of $M(0)$. I was expecting this to be $1$ given that X is a PDF. But as you can see, $M(0)$ would be undefined. Why doesn't $M(0) = 1$? Also, to answer the question "Find the value of $M(0)$", should I just say that $M(0)$ is undefined?

Comment: Instead of directly evaluating at $t = 0$, you just take the limit $t \to 0$. You can see it is in the $\frac {0} {0}$ indeterminate form, so you can find the limit, e.g. by L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: Ohh true. And that gives $1$. I just noticed that the question after this is asking for that limit. But does this mean that $M(0) = 1$ or is it undefined, to answer the question.

Comment: This is a little bit subtle here. By definition, the MGF is $E[e^{tX}] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{tx}f_X(x)dx$ and actually, all your subsequent integration steps are based on the case that $t \neq 0$. When you put $t = 0$, you immediately obtain $1$ here.

Comment: Nvm, I got it now. Thanks a lot. Copy your comments down below into an answer.